# Flex Layout not responding properly in reactJs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently what Im trying to achieve is this:
[image]

But I tried this using flex attribute but the layout is messed up. Here is my code for the same.

```
<div className="contact-container" style={{flexDirection:"row",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC"}}>
        <div style={{padding:"30px"}}>
          <div style={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
            <p style={{color:"#0E2043",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC", fontSize:"22px",fontWeight:"700", textAlign:"justify"}}>If you are looking to enjoy exactly these benefits, Passport Legacy is here to assist you with your second citizenship. </p>
            <p style={{color:"#0E2043", paddingTop:"30px",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC", textAlign:"justify"}}>If you would like more information about any of the qualifying programs, or our services, please do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{padding:"30px"}}>
          <div>
          <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
              </div>
            <div style={{width:"100%",display:"flex", flexWrap:"wrap", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
            <input style={{padding:"5px",width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="email"/>
            </div>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
            <input style={{padding:"5px",width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="phone"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Subject"/>
              </div>

              <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <textarea style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} rows="4" placeholder="Message"/>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Ive added a sandbox too, Please feel free to make changes.
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-dawn-l27wy?file=/src/App.tsx:71-1766

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with a little changes, I made it responsive too for width less than 400px.

```js
const App=()=>{
return(
  <div className="contact-container" style={{backgroundColor:"#ECECEC"}}>
        <div style={{padding:"30px"}}>
          <div style={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
            <p style={{color:"#0E2043",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC", fontSize:"22px",fontWeight:"700", textAlign:"justify"}}>If you are looking to enjoy exactly these benefits, Passport Legacy is here to assist you with your second citizenship. </p>
            <p style={{color:"#0E2043", paddingTop:"30px",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC", textAlign:"justify"}}>If you would like more information about any of the qualifying programs, or our services, please do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{padding:"30px"}}>
          <div>
          <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
              </div>
            <div style={{width:"100%",display:"flex", flexWrap:"wrap", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
            <input style={{padding:"5px",width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="email"/>
            </div>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
            <input style={{padding:"5px",width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="phone"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Subject"/>
              </div>

              <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <textarea style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} rows="4" placeholder="Message"/>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
)}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.contact-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contact-container > div {
  width:50%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.contact-container {
  flex-direction: column;
}
 .contact-container > div {
  width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is specify the "width" for the "div" on the left.

```
<div style={{padding:"30px", width:"50%"}}>
```

Comment: I understand you don't have enough reputation but this is not a correct way to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a `ReactJS` issue. It is just you are not configuring the flexbox propertly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container input,
.container textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.container input {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.container .flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .flex input:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.container textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <div class="flex">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject">
    <textarea id="" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works?